# Group chat in Python

Tags: python, sockets, python-multithreading

I am writing a group chat code, which is consisted of server.py and client.py. Basically, any message sent by any client is visible to all clients.  It runs normal until one of the clients close the connection. When a client closes the connection, server cannot accept new clients. I get the following error: Connected by  ('127.0.0.1', 11142)
Exception: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not
a socket

Code for server.py

```
from socket import *
import select
import sys
import threading

QUIT = False

class Server:
    def __init__(self):
        self.host = "127.0.0.1"
        self.port = 9999
        self.threads = []
        self.backlog = 10 

    def run(self):
        all_good = False
        while not all_good:
            try:
                all_good = False
                self.sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
                self.sock.bind((self.host, self.port))
                self.sock.listen(self.backlog)
                all_good= True
                print("Server started at "+self.host+":"+str(self.port))
                break
            except Exception as err:
                print('Socket connection error... ')
                self.sock.close()
        try:
            while not QUIT:
                try:
                    client, addr = self.sock.accept()
                except socket.timeout:
                    continue
                new_thread = Client(client)
                print("Connected by ", addr)
                msg = ("Connected by %s at %s" %(new_thread.name, addr)).encode()
                for each in self.threads:
                    each.client.send(msg)

                self.threads.append(new_thread)
                new_thread.start()

                for thread in self.threads:
                    if not thread.isAlive():
                        self.threads.remove(thread)
                        thread.join()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
                print("Terminating by Ctrl+C")
        except Exception as err:
            print("Exception: %s\nClosing" %err)
        for thread in self.threads:
            thread.join()
        self.sock.close()


class Client(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, client):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.client = client

    def run(self):
        global QUIT
        done = False

        while not done:
            try:
                cmd = self.client.recv(1024).decode()
                if cmd.startswith("/name"):
                    self.client.send("Enter your username: ".encode())
                    old_name = self.name
                    self.name = self.client.recv(1024).decode()
                    msg = "%s has changed his username to %s" %(old_name, self.name)
                    for each in server.threads:
                        if each != self and each.isAlive():
                            each.client.send(msg.encode())
                    self.client.send(("Your username has been changed to %s" %self.name).encode())
                elif cmd == "/quit":
                    self.client.send("exit".encode())
                    server.threads.remove(self)
                    for each in server.threads:
                            each.client.send(("%s Disconnected" %self.name).encode())
                    QUIT = True
                    done = True
                else:
                    msg = "%s===>%s" %(self.name, cmd)
                    for each in server.threads:
                        if each != self:
                            each.client.send(msg.encode())
            except Exception as e:
                print("Connection lost", e)
                self.client.close()
                done = True
                continue

        self.client.close()
        return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = Server()
    server.run()

    print("Terminated")
```

Code for client.py

```
from socket import *
import sys
import threading
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 9999

class listen(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, client):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.client = client
        self.setDaemon(True)

    def run(self):
        while(True):
            data = self.client.recv(1024)
            if data.decode() == "exit":
                sys.exit(1)
            print(data.decode())




if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        clientSocket.connect((host, port))
        print("Welcome to chat!")
        print("Type your message and press 'Enter' to send.")
        print("Send '/name' command to change your username.")
        print("Send '/quit' command to quit.")
    except error as e:
            if clientSocket:
                clientSocket.close()
            print("Could not open a socket: "+ str(e))
            sys.exit(1)

    l = listen(clientSocket)
    l.start()
    message = input()
    while message!="/quit":
        #sys.stdout.flush()
        clientSocket.send(message.encode())
        #data = self.clientSocket.recv(1024)
        #data = data.decode()
        #print("Recieved: "+str(data))
        message= input()
    clientSocket.close()
```

Comment: On what line does the error occur? Please provide the full error message, including the (relevant) stack trace

Comment: I am running it through terminal and that is all I am getting. All I can tell is that the following exception is thrown:
except Exception as err:
            print("Exception: %s\nClosing" %err)